# Spring Boot routeprovider does not work

Tags: java, html, spring

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">


    <title>Internet Movıe Database - Search, Edit, Update, Delete, Add</title>



    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://rawgit.com/iamisti/mdDataTable/master/dist/md-data-table-style.css'>

    <style>
        html, body{
            background: #DDDDDD;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
    </script>



</head>

<body>

<div ng-app="exampleApp" ng-controller="ExampleController" layout-margin>

    <md-toolbar layout="row" layout-align="left center" layout-padding>
        <h1 class="md-title">Internet Movie Database</h1>
    </md-toolbar>


    <form name="userForm">
        <md-input-container>
            <label>title</label>
            <input name="title" ng-model="title" required md-maxlength="20" minlength="2">
            <div ng-messages="userForm.title.$error" ng-show="userForm.title.$dirty">
                <div ng-message="required">This is required!</div>
                <div ng-message="md-maxlength">That's too long!</div>
                <div ng-message="minlength">That's too short!</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
            <label>actor</label>
            <input name="actor" ng-model="actor" required md-maxlength="200" minlength="2">
            <div ng-messages="userForm.actor.$error" ng-show="userForm.actor.$dirty">
                <div ng-message="required">This is required!</div>
                <div ng-message="md-maxlength">That's too long!</div>
                <div ng-message="minlength">That's too short!</div>
            </div>
        </md-input-container>

        <md-button class="btn1" ng-click="addMovie(title,actor)">Add Movie</md-button>
    </form>

    <mdt-table table-card="{visible: true, title: 'Movie List'}"
               selectable-rows="true"
               alternate-headers="'contextual'"
               sortable-columns="tableIsSortable"
               selected-row-callback="selectedRowCallback(rows)">

        <mdt-header-row>
            <mdt-column align-rule="left">id</mdt-column>
            <mdt-column align-rule="right">Name</mdt-column>
            <mdt-column align-rule="right">Actors</mdt-column>
            <mdt-column align-rule="right">Options</mdt-column>

        </mdt-header-row>
        <mdt-row ng-repeat="task in tasks"
            table-row-id="task.id" md-on-select="onSelect(task)">
            <mdt-cell>{{task.id}}</mdt-cell>
            <mdt-cell>{{task.title}}</mdt-cell>
            <mdt-cell>{{task.actor}}</mdt-cell>
            <mdt-cell><md-button> Flat Button </md-button>

              </mdt-cell>



        </mdt-row>
    </mdt-table>
    <div layout="row" flex>
        <md-sidenav md-is-locked-open="true">
            <md-list>
                <md-list-item ng-repeat="aPage in pages">
                    <md-button flex ng-click="selectPage(aPage)" ng-class="{'md-primary md-raised' : aPage.name === selectedPage.name }">
                        {{aPage.name}}
                    </md-button>
                </md-list-item>
            </md-list>
        </md-sidenav>

        <iframe flex scrolling='yes' ng-src='{{examplePageUrl}}' frameborder='no' allowtransparency='true' allowfullscreen='true'></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="//assets.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-f961f59a28ef4fd551736b43f94620b5.js"></script>

<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-aria.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular-material-icons/0.6.0/angular-material-icons.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://rawgit.com/iamisti/mdDataTable/master/dist/md-data-table-templates.js'></script>
<script src='https://rawgit.com/iamisti/mdDataTable/master/dist/md-data-table.js'></script>

<script>
    (function () {
        'use strict';
        angular.module('exampleApp', [
            'ngMaterial',
            'mdDataTable'
        ]);
        angular.module('exampleApp').controller('ExampleController', function ($scope, $mdToast,$window,$http) {

            $scope.addMovie=function(title,actor){
              //  $window.alert("ititle actor "+title+actor)
                //  $scope.title="title clicked "+title;

                //  $scope.actor="actor clicked "+actor;

                // $scope.added="the movie '"+title+"' with those actor '"+actor+"' added successfully";

                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": "55d5927329415b000100003b63a9e1b480b64a1040a902a26da862d3",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
                    },

                    url: 'http://localhost:8181/movies/add/'+title+"/"+actor
                }).then(function successCallback() {//$window.alert("in addmoviesuccess");
                    //  $scope.check = response.data;

                    //    $scope.names = response.data.title;

                    $scope.listMovie();

                });

                //$window.alert("bitiste addmovie")
                // $scope.listMovie();
            },

                    $scope.onSelect = function (task) {
                        $window.alert("eonselect1");

                    }

            $scope.selectedRowCallback = function (rows) {//$window.alert("in delete: "+rows.length);
                //$mdToast.show($mdToast.simple().content('Deleted row id(s): ' + rows).hideDelay(3000));
//$scope.previousRow = rows;
               // $scope.rows
                if(rows.length>1){


    $window.alert("Error! You can only delete one movie at one time");
   // exit_to_app;
    //$window.alert("return sonrasi");

                }
else{//$window.alert("else1");
                $http({
                    method: 'DELETE',
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": "55d5927329415b000100003b63a9e1b480b64a1040a902a26da862d3",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
                    },
                    url: 'http://localhost:8181/movies/delete/'+rows[0]
                }).then(function successCallback() {// $window.alert("in removemoviesuccess");
                   // $scope.listMovie();
                })
} // $scope.listMovie();
            };

            $scope.listMovie=function(){
                //      var list = 1
                  //  $window.alert("in listmovie");
                $scope.check='NO';
                //    $scope.list="list clicked "+list;
                //   $window.alert(" listmovie "+list);
                // $scope.listed="the movies are listing: "+list;
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {

                        "Authorization": "55d5927329415b000100003b63a9e1b480b64a1040a902a26da862d3",
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                    },
                    url: 'http://localhost:8181/movies/list'
                }).then(function successCallback(response) { //$window.alert("in listmoviesuccess");
                            //  $scope.check = response.data;//
                            console.log(response);
                            $scope.tasks = response.data;
                            //    $scope.names = response.data.title;



                        }, function errorCallback(response) {//$window.alert("in listmovie err");
                            //  console.log(response);
                            // $scope.check = response;
                        }
                );

                //$window.alert("in listmovie end");
            };
            $scope.listMovie();
        });
        exampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
            function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.
                when('/movies', {
                    templateUrl: 'movies/main',
                    controller: 'todoController'
                }).
                when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'movies/main',
                    controller: 'todoController'
                }).
                when('/movies/', {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
                    controller: 'todoController'
                }).
                when('/list', {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/phone-deffaatail.html',
                    controller: 'todoController'
                }).
                when('/movies/list', {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/sss.html',
                    controller: 'todoController'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/phones'
                });
            }]);


    }());
    //@ sourceURL=pen.js
</script>


<script>
    if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
        window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
    }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

this is my main html page, test.html. It is page of CRUD operations. It connects to database to manipulate. This is my controller:

```
import org.infoowl.domain.Movie;
import org.infoowl.repository.MovieRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by caneraydin on 15.03.2016.
 */

@RestController
//@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "movies")
@CrossOrigin(value = "http://localhost:63342", maxAge = 3600)
public class MovieController {

    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;
    private Movie movie;

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home(){
        System.out.println("moviecontroller homeda");
        return "forward:/test.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add/{name}/{actor}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public HashMap<Movie, Long> add(@PathVariable String name, @PathVariable String actor){
        System.out.println("moviecontroller addeda");
        //Movie movie = new Movie("Scarface","AlPacino");
     movie = new Movie(name,actor);
        movieRepository.save(movie);
        HashMap<Movie,Long> hash = new HashMap<Movie,Long> ();
        return hash;
    }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public HashMap<Movie, Long> delete(@PathVariable Long id ){
        System.out.println("moviecontroller deleteda");
        movieRepository.delete(id);
        HashMap<Movie,Long> hash = new HashMap<Movie,Long> ();
        return hash;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Iterable<Movie> list() {
        System.out.println("moviecontroller listed");

        return movieRepository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}/{name}/{actor}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public HashMap<Movie, Long> edit(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable String name, @PathVariable String actor){
        System.out.println("moviecontroller editeda");
        movieRepository.delete(id);
        movie = new Movie(name,actor);
        movieRepository.save(movie);
        HashMap<Movie,Long> hash = new HashMap<Movie,Long> ();
        return hash;
    }
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getIndexPage() {
        return "x";
    }

   // @RestController
     //class HomeController {
      //  @RequestMapping("/")
      //  public String index() {
       //     return "test";
       // }
   // }
}
```

You can see routeprovider inside html

```
exampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
                function($routeProvider) {
                    $routeProvider.
                    when('/movies', {
                        templateUrl: 'movies/main',
                        controller: 'todoController'
                    }).
                    when('/', {
                        templateUrl: 'movies/main',
                        controller: 'todoController'
                    }).
                    when('/movies/', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html',
                        controller: 'todoController'
                    }).
                    when('/list', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/phone-deffaatail.html',
                        controller: 'todoController'
                    }).
                    when('/movies/list', {
                        templateUrl: 'partials/sss.html',
                        controller: 'todoController'
                    }).
                    otherwise({
                        redirectTo: '/phones'
                    });
                }]);
```

After running when i try to go to 
http://localhost:8181/movies/list
it shows json data

http://localhost:8181/movies/ shows only x

http://localhost:8181/movies/home shows forward:/test.html

And also, to open that html, i click right and open in browser and it goes to

http://localhost:63342/InternetMovieDatabase/static/test.html
 that url to show the html.

it is a single page application. I just tried controller url like list.But i couldnot manage.

resources
-static
--bower_components

-test.html
templates
application.properties

organization is like that. Ialso copied test.html to templates but nothing changed.

This is main java

```
package org.infoowl;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class InternetMovieDatabaseApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InternetMovieDatabaseApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(InternetMovieDatabaseApplication.class);
    }
}
```

https://github.com/caneraydinbey/InternetMovieDatabasev3

also you can see here everything.

Why doesnot it work?

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it? Per your explanation and the code you have posted, it does exactly what it is supposed to do. I suspect you are getting standard URLs confused with Angular URLs (for which you have completely forgotten to mention anything about in this problem description)

Comment: When i run application, should not it open the test.html page itself? this is standart url http://localhost:63342/InternetMovieDatabase/static/test.html this is angular http://localhost:8181/movies/list So, only first one can have routeprpvider, right?